# Moment business days does not work when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I use a function (func1) inside another function (func2). Func1 contains logic and moment. Inside func2 I setup the moment configuration.

```
import moment from 'moment-business-days';

const func1 = () => {
     return moment('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY').isBusinessDay();
}

const func2 = () => {
     moment.updateLocale('us', {
       holidays: ['01-01-2019','29-10-2019'],
       holidayFormat: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
     });
     //... some logic.

    console.log('result 1', moment('01-01-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY').isBusinessDay());

    const result = func1();
    console.log('result 2', result);

}
```

When I enter the page, `func2` works first and it works properly, both consoles return `false`; however, `result 2` returns `true` as I refresh the page while `result 1` remains correct.

Comment: It may be a typo in the post but in func2 you are calling func2 again.

Comment: As mentioned in @barteezy, this code results in infinite loop if `func2()` is called. If I correct that, the code works perfectly fine (The function returns  `isBusinessDay` as `false` ). So the problem should be somewhere else  `//... some logic.`

Comment: @barteezy it was a typo, sorry, edited.

Comment: @nithin  there is nothing to do with moment in `//... some logic.`. The code should work perfectly but `result 2` returns `true` unfortunately. If a log `result 1` under `result 2`, the problem still the same.

Comment: Did you try to run the code you have posted ?. It works perfectly fine for me. The possible reasons `func1` can return `true` is `If func1 is called before moment.updateLocale` or somewhere else you are resetting the locale using updateLocale function

Comment: Of course, I did try and it worked the way I described. Although I logged the locale before and after it gives different results, I could not see a change or update in `moment.updateLocale`. @NithinThampi